# ansible: check if one of array elements is in variable string

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I've got a list in ansible:

```
ssh_port_patterns: [
  "domain.tld",
  "example.tld",
  "something.tld"
]
```

and I'd like to run one task, only if its inventory_hostname will containt one of these items phrase. For example task should be run when inventory_hostname will be set to: `extra.domain.tld`, but shouldn't in case of `something.else.tld`

Is it possible to make such check with ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [Ansible fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#discovering-variables-facts-and-magic-variables) for `ansible_domain` which usually contains the domain suffix of the host on which Ansible is performing tasks. The *simplest way* would be to match this against the list `ssh_port_patterns`.

Example `debug` message will only run when the suffix of hostname is in the list:

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "run on {{ ansible_hostname }}"
    when: ansible_domain in ssh_port_patterns
```

**Update:**

If this has to be achieved only with `inventory_hostname` for whatever reeason, then `split` and `join` can be used to form the domain suffix and matched with the list.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "run on {{ ansible_hostname }}"
      when: inventory_hostname.split('.')[1:]|join('.') in ssh_port_patterns
```

Comment: It will not work in this case because on some servers domain name will be different than inventory_hostname

Comment: I've updated the answer to derive the domain suffix from `inventory_hostname` itself and match it with a list.

Comment: So simple :D thank you. I thought it will be needed to use some kind of complicated functions.